# Как сделать кнопку рабочей, что бы она ссылалась на другую страницу сайта?

Tags: html

Как сделать кнопку рабочей, что бы она ссылалась на другую страницу сайта?!
При том что в коде значится как галерея, как это исправить?
[image: Кнопка]
[image: Код картинки]

Comment: Может ссылку проставить?..

Comment: В `<a href="#" ... ">` за место `#` поставить ссылку

Comment: Спасибо сработало!